# Which construction algorithm does scikit-learn's ball tree use?

Tags: scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

Which construction algorithm does ball Tree use in scikit learn?

Comment: For context to readers there are a number of construction algorithms for BallTrees: http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/ftp/global/pub/techreports/1989/tr-89-063.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git history shows the k-d construction algorithm is used for the BallTree algorithm. You can find a good write-up by Jake VanderPlas discussing the implementation approaches [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/04/29/benchmarking-nearest-neighbor-searches-in-python/).